# How to visualize this data clarifying in R and recognize patterns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

This is my dataframe:

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1ZmQ.png)

Output dput(dataframe):

```
structure(list(ChargePoint_skey = c(2174, 2174, 2174, 2239, 2239, 
2266, 2266, 2266, 2266, 2266), MonthYear = structure(c(17532, 
17563, 17591, 17956, 17987, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 17652
), class = "Date"), aantalsessies = c(16L, 15L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 
61L, 29L, 33L, 13L, 14L)), .Names = c("ChargePoint_skey", "MonthYear", 
"aantalsessies"), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(ChargePoint_skey = 
c(2174, 
2239, 2266), .rows = list(1:3, 4:5, 6:10)), .Names = c("ChargePoint_skey", 
".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

As you can see there are a lot of groups in the column 'ChargePoint_skey' because there are a lot different ChargePoints. I want to visualize this data to recognize patterns about all the ChargePoints. Does anybody have a suggestion for a type of visualization? I was thinking of a stacked barchart like this:

[stackedbarchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iuy6N.png)

But this isn't an option for me since I have many different ChargePoints in my data.

I hope somebody can help me with this!

Comment: Please add your dataframe using `dput(yourdata)` do not include screenshots!

Comment: Please edit the question and paste the output from `dput()`.

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried a 3D plot - using `plotly` or the like to make it interactive? From the looks of it, your data consists of discrete series (`ChargePoint`) across multiple years (`MonthYear`) and some numeric value (`aantalsessies`).

Comment: @Gautam it sounds look a good answer to my question. Unfortunately, I do not have any experience with plotly or interactive plots. Could you help me further with this method?

Comment: @daniël.vandijk I added an answer to show how you could use `plotly` for your problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to post as a comment so I'm posting an answer.

3D plots (surface/scatter etc.) can be quite useful for visualizing data. Here's an example of a surface plot from one of my previous projects that I used to examine the relationship b/w the three variables and where the problem becomes infeasible (voids in the plot). This is an example of a full-factorial DOE.

[image]

Back to you problem now - I prefer using `plotly` for an interactive output that you can play around with. This (imo) is better than static tools that can only be manipulated via code (rotations/pan/zoom etc.).

**CODE**

```
library(plotly) 
# dat is the data.frame from your dput output 

plt <- plot_ly(dat, x = ~MonthYear, y = ~ChargePoint_skey, y = ~aantalsessies) %>% 
  add_markers()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Since this is a small sample of the dataset, the plot is rather sparse. With a larger dataset you'd likely get some better insights.

You can refer to https://plotly.com/r/3d-scatter-plots/ for more information. The plots themselves can be saved as html files (can be opened in a browser) for sharing - using `htmlwdigets` package.

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widget = as_widget(plt), file = 'myfile.html', selfcontained = T, title = 'my tab title')
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot ChargePoint_skeys (+- 363), I think it still will be an unclear visualisation than. But I tried to run the following code:
`
plt <- plot_ly(vraag_1, x = ~MonthYear, y = ~ChargePoint_skey, y = ~aantalsessies) %>% 
  add_markers()

`

Unfortunately, plt becomes a list of 8 in my global environment .. I can't see the plot. Do you know how I can make the plot visible? Sorry for my late reaction btw.

Comment: the plot itself is a list. You can view it by calling it in the console - if using base R then it should appear in a browser, if you're using an IDE like Rstudio then the plot is displayed in the "Viewer" window. In my answer I also described a way to save the plot as a standalone html file - which is saved to your working directory and can then be opened in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using `geom_tile()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(ChargePoint_skey),y=factor(MonthYear),
             fill=aantalsessies))+
  geom_tile()+xlab('ChargePoint_skey')+ylab('MonthYear')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Since the data exists of a lot ChargePoint_skey's, this won't be clarifying. The range of the x-axis will be too big.

Comment: do you have any other suggestions? :)

Comment: Maybe using facets